pre-launch testing error - com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.activities.BlankActivity
I'm trying to publish my app on the Play Store, but after uploading AAB, the revision of Google sais me that there is an ANR error that I cannot reproduce. It's failing in the test that they run on a device (attach a video in the detail) and they send me the stack in which I can see that there is not a problem in my code?
    Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.instrumentations.uid/com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.activities.BlankActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.activities.BlankActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wsdayc00LelZy9H42FfBQg==/com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.instrumentations.uid-fMhyZNXgAOWLG3gX_FGZVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wsdayc00LelZy9H42FfBQg==/com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.instrumentations.uid-fMhyZNXgAOWLG3gX_FGZVA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3613)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3864)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2253)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7870)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.activities.BlankActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wsdayc00LelZy9H42FfBQg==/com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.instrumentations.uid-fMhyZNXgAOWLG3gX_FGZVA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wsdayc00LelZy9H42FfBQg==/com.google.testing.helium.utp.android.companion.instrumentations.uid-fMhyZNXgAOWLG3gX_FGZVA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:95)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1285)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3600)

What I can do? how to talk with google?
